# Ubuntu 19 it's showing booting page from long time after restarting

Tags: 19.04, ubuntu-one, restart

I installed Ubuntu 19 in HP 14q laptop and there is problem with WiFi adapater and I fixed that issue then I restarted my system but it's still booting from long time

Comment: Does Ubuntu finish to boot after a long time ? Or it is stuck ?

Comment: Can you try and press Ctrl+F1 while running into the alleged freeze?

Comment: I'm curious why the `ubuntu-one` tag is selected?

Comment: I am trying to use ubuntu tag but system not accepting that and allowing ubuntu-one tag with auto populate